# How to add two instances of my custom class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I want to run this code **(must) including** the attribute `value` next to `total` in the `print` section. What code should I insert inside the class to do it?

```
class Random:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.x + other.x


p1 = Random(2)
p2 = Random(3)

total = p1 + p2

print(total.value)
```

Comment: Maybe  create another class for the return value.

Comment: What do you mean by variable total?

Comment: `total` is just an `int`, not an instance of `Random` (or any other class with a `value` attribute).

Comment: ```print(p1.add(p2))```

Comment: There would be a solution if the body of your `__add__` method looked like this: `return Random(self.x + other.x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return an instance of `Random` in your `__add__` method and add a property with the name `value` for the class.

```
class Random:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Random(self.x + other.x)

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.x


p1 = Random(2)
p2 = Random(3)

total = p1 + p2

print(total.value)
```

---

Of course the better option would be to replace the instance attribute `x` with `value`. Then there's no need for the property.

```
class Random:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.value = x

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Random(self.value + other.value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make `total` a `Random` as well.

```
class Random:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Random(self.value + other.value)


p1: Random = Random(2)
p2: Random  = Random(3)

total: Random = p1 + p2

print(total.value)
```

Comment: Probably makes more sense for `Random.__add__` itself to return an instance of `Random`.

Comment: @chepner I agree. Code was modified.